# Using multiple wildcards in one glob

Tags: bash, command-line, wildcards

In my directory, I have a list of files with different extensions such as

```
file-abc-12.out
file-abc-12.csv
file-abc-12.txt
file-xyz-12.out
file-xyz-12.csv
file-xyz-12.txt
file-abc-04.out
file-abc-04.csv
file-abc-04.txt
file-xyz-04.out
file-xyz-04.csv
file-xyz-04.txt
```

If I only want to list the files that contain abc and end in a .out, how would I do that. I want to perform a `ls` or a `find` using two pattern matching searches `*abc*` and `*out`. I only know how to search one or the other at a time, how would I have it search for file names with both conditions?

Comment: `ls *abc*.out`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti should be `printf '%s\n' *abc*.out`

Comment: From the OP:  "I want to perform a `ls` or `find`".

Comment: The trick is in realising that there is no such thing as a file extension: the dot in the file-name is not special. The idea of filename extensions comes from Microsoft's windows/dos versions <= 3.1 and cp/m.

Comment: @cuonglm there's no reason to use `printf` here, why? The OP hasn't suggested they want to parse the output, only list the names. Why would `printf` be useful here?

Comment: @terdon: `ls` can cause argument list too long error when you have too many files matches the glob. `printf` is better, it's builtin in all modern shell. When you do need a filter, then use `find` or `zsh` if available.

Answer (score 10):

This will give you what you want:

```
$ find . -name '*abc*' -o -name '*out'
```

Comment: Thank you for responding first and foremost.

The command you gave seems to list all the files that have 'abc' contained in the file name OR end with '.out'. I want a command that will list all the files that contain 'abc' AND end with '.out'

Comment: Odd, this doesn't work for me.  It's not giving me any results.

Answer (score 4):

I'm interpreting the "and" used in the question as a strict "logical and", i.e. as "find files whose names match *both* `*abc*` and `*out`".

You may use multiple wildcards in one filename globbing pattern:

```
$ ls *abc*out
```

or

```
$ find . -type f -name "*abc*out"
```

for example.

The pattern `*abc*out` would match any name containing the string `abc` and then ending in `out`.

If no file matches the pattern, the pattern will be left unexpanded. If that happens, `ls` will get the pattern `*abc*out` as the argument rather than a valid filename, and will complain about `ls: cannot access *abc*out: No such file or directory`.

To make `bash` display an error about not being able to expand a file globbing pattern rather than passing the unexpanded pattern to `ls`, set the `failglob` shell option:

```
bash-4.4$ ls *abc*out
ls: *abc*out: No such file or directory

bash-4.4$ shopt -s failglob

bash-4.4$ ls *abc*out
bash: no match: *abc*out
```

Comment: Hmm my shell doesn't seem to accept that. I get the following message:

`ls: cannot access *abc*out: No such file or directory`

Comment: @TySeyoum This is because you don't actually have any file matching that pattern. Since no file matches the pattern, the pattern is left unexpanded, `ls` tries to use it as a filename, but fails.

Answer (score -3):

The solution I found to work for me involved using grep. It follows:

`$ ls *out | grep "abc"`

Comment: Please don't use this! It will break on strange file names and all you need is `ls *abc*out`. If what you show works, then so does `ls *abc*out`. The error you menition under Kusalananda's answer suggests you might have run `ls '*abc*out'` instead. For more on why this is a bad approach, see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @terdon You're exactly right. I tried it again and it worked. Thank you!